# Selecting data from three MySQL tables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, union

I have had a look and I am really struggling to see how I can overcome this. I have looked at `UNION/UNION ALL` and `JOIN` but I cant get it to work.

Basically, I have data from three MySQL tables. The three tables have form data from it and are named *Fleet*, *Facilities*, *HAS*. The data have similar headers but different information. They all share the same 4 headers:

`ticket | agentname | dept | resolved`.

I have the below PHP code to display this in an HTML table but I can not get it to display from all three tables. (I can only post two images)

[image: Facility Table]

[image: Fleet Table]

```
$mysqli=mysqli_connect("example","root","toor","site");
include('config.php');    //include of db config file
include ('paginate.php'); //include of paginat page

$per_page = 25;         // number of results to show per page
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM fleet
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT * FROM has
                        ORDER resolved BY ASC;");
```

I am not a web programmer. I have learned what I know from youtube and google. Please explain where possible your answer.

Comment: what's the tables structure ?

Comment: You should show the error you get or output if no error

Comment: I have added 2 images on to the main post. I get no error

Comment: *I can not get it to display from all three tables* is not clear enough. What is your current output and desired output? `JOIN` (wide format) and `UNION` (long format) do very different things.

Comment: What information/output do you need?

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error: ORDER resolved BY ASC, that should be : ORDER BY resolved ASC

Have you try to specify columns in your selects? Try something like this:

```
    SELECT ticket, agentname, dept, resolved FROM fleet
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ticket, agentname, dept, resolved FROM has
    ORDER BY resolved ASC;
```